# Task.IsFaulted is not working in my .Net core application

Tags: .net-core

`Task.IsFaulted` is not capturing exception. It seems that `IsFault` is not working. It is sending to else block even the condition is false.  Can you please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

```
public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string userid, string fullname, string comment)
        {
            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");
            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

            string email = (string)obj["SendEmailTo"];
            string subject = "Feedback by: " + fullname + " (" + userid + ")";

         //  await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);

            var result = _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);

            string responseString = "";
            if (result.IsFaulted)
            {
                responseString = @" 
                                <!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset='utf - 8' />
                                    <title>MCP Feedback Facility</title>
                                </head >
                                <body >
                                    <br />
                                 <br />
                                 <br />
                                    <p>Sorry, your feedback submission was not completed successfully</p>
                                </body>
                                </html>
                                ";
            }
          else
            {
                responseString = @" 
                                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                                    <html>
                                    <head>
                                        <meta charset='utf - 8' />
                                        <title>MCP Feedback Facility</title>
                                    </head >
                                    <body >
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Feedback submitted successfully.</p>
                                      </body>
                                    </html>
                                    ";

            }

            return await Task.FromResult<string>(responseString);
```

Comment: Perhaps it will fault in the future? Do you wait for it to do anything at all?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I do not understand what are you saying. What will be the fix for this. Why it is always hitting `else` block even it is false.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669369/task-isfaulted-is-not-catching-exception-in-my-net-core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `IsFaulted`, just use `try`/`catch`:

```
try
{
  await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
  return @" 
                                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                                    <html>
                                    <head>
                                        <meta charset='utf - 8' />
                                        <title>MCP Feedback Facility</title>
                                    </head >
                                    <body >
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <p>Feedback submitted successfully.</p>
                                      </body>
                                    </html>
                                    ";
}
catch
{
  return @" 
                                <!DOCTYPE html>
                                <html>
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset='utf - 8' />
                                    <title>MCP Feedback Facility</title>
                                </head >
                                <body >
                                    <br />
                                 <br />
                                 <br />
                                    <p>Sorry, your feedback submission was not completed successfully</p>
                                </body>
                                </html>
                                ";

}
```

Side note: [`return await Task.FromResult<string>(responseString);` is just a less efficient and less maintainable version of `return responseString;`](https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/1155827537232220161)

Comment: Even if it is not sending email, it is going to try block. Do I need to comment `var result = _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);`

Comment: What do you mean? There's an `await`, so it won't block.