# Task.IsFaulted is not catching exception in my .Net core

Tags: .net-core

`Task.IsFaulted` is not catching exception. It is sending to else block even the condition is false. Can you please suggest me where I am doing wrong. I tried implementing `try... catch` but still not working.

```cs
public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string userid, string fullname, string comment)
{
    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

    string email = (string)obj["SendEmailTo"];
    string subject = "Feedback by: " + fullname + " (" + userid + ")";

    //  await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);

    var result = _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);

    string responseString = "";
    if (result.IsFaulted)
    {
        try
        {
            responseString = @" 
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <p>Sorry, your feedback was not completed successfully</p>
                </body>
                </html>";
        }
        catch
        {
            responseString = @" 
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <p>Feedback submitted successfully.</p>
                </body>
                </html>";
        }
    }

    return await Task.FromResult<string>(responseString);
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61667952/task-isfaulted-is-not-working-in-my-net-core-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsFaulted` doesn't wait for the task to complete or fault, it just checks the current state of the `Task`. In your case you're asynchronously sending an email, not waiting for that operation to complete, then testing the state of a `Task` that is likely still running (and not in a faulted state yet).

To fix this, you can wrap **an awaited call** in a try/catch block...

```cs
try
{
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    return @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Sorry, your feedback was not completed successfully</p>
</body>
</html>";
}

return @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p >Feedback submitted successfully.</p>
</body>
</html>";
```

...or factor towards `Task<bool>` returning methods where you can test the succeeded/failed result once the task completes e.g.

```cs
public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string userid, string fullname, string comment)
{
    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("appsettings.json");
    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

    string email = (string)obj["SendEmailTo"];
    string subject = "Feedback by: " + fullname + " (" + userid + ")";

    async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // TODO: Log exception etc.
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    var succeeded = await SendEmailAsync();

    if (succeeded)
    {
        return @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Feedback submitted successfully.</p>
</body>
</html>";
    }
    else
    {
        return @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Sorry, your feedback was not completed successfully</p>
</body>
</html>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync()
    {
      `. it complains about async there and also shows invalid expression at the end of first line.

Comment: @MVC - my example uses local function syntax so would need C# 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SendEmailAsync()` looks like an asynchronous method, and it most likely returns a `Task`. If you want to check if the task succeeded, you have to wait until it finishes.

```
var result = _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
result.Wait();
if (result.IsFaulted)
....
```

or

```
var result = _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
await result;
if (result.IsFaulted)
....
```

Depending on your `SendEmailAsync()` implementation you can probably just use `try/catch` with `await`:

```
try
{
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(contentRootPath, email, subject, comment, userid, fullname);
    ...
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `result.Wait()` and `await result` will both throw if the `Task` is faulted so the `if (result.IsFaulted)` test afterwards will be unreachable in that case.